# Extract a particular table from multi-table html file using perl

Tags: perl, html-parsing, extract

I have a html file with three tables. But I want to extract only one table of the three. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good module for extracting parts of a HTML document is [`HTML::Query`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aQuery).

It provides a jQuery-like interface for selecting what part of a document to extract.

Comment: [Mojo::DOM](http://p3rl.org/Mojo::DOM) provides a full set of CSS3 selectors including [`nth-of-type`](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM/CSS#Enthoftypen), which it seems that HTML::Query lacks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using known `Perl` modules like :

- `LWP`
- `WWW::Mechanize`
- `HTML::TreeBuilder`
- `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`

All are on http://search.cpan.org

The last Perl module is really usefull, you can use `Xpath` expressions like :

```
//table[0]/tr[3]/td[2]/text()
```

by example, to print the text of the second `td` element in the third `tr` from the first `table`.