# How to extract each table from multi-table html file to a new text file

Tags: perl, extract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract a particular table from multi-table html file using perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038441/extract-a-particular-table-from-multi-table-html-file-using-perl)

I need to extract each table in a multi-table html file to a new text file. Can you please show me how to do this in perl using an example?

Comment: See module [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/~msisk/HTML-TableExtract-2.11/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm)

Comment: You have asked this question four times today. http://stackoverflow.com/users/1769222/user1769222

Answer (score 0):

You're using HTML::TableExtract, right? You can specify which table you want to extract specifying values for the contructor's `depth` and `count` arguments.

```
# The second top-level table.
my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( depth => 0, count => 2 );
```